# Google Search Console reports missing "item" in "itemListElement" in breadcrumbs in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Google Search Console complains about a missing `item` in breadcrumbs if a category without a page is used in the navigation structure (the category has then no link in the breadcrumbs).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Shopware 6 template. It was reported in the issuetracker as [NEXT-22037](https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-22037) but has not been fixed yet. To fix it, create a new file `src/Resources/views/storefront/layout/breadcrumb.html.twig` in your plugin/theme and paste the code:

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/layout/breadcrumb.html.twig' %}

{% block layout_breadcrumb_list %}
    <ol class="breadcrumb"
        itemscope
        itemtype="https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">

        {% set position = 1 %}

        {% for breadcrumbCategory in breadcrumbCategories %}
            {% set key = breadcrumbCategory.id %}
            {% set name = breadcrumbCategory.translated.name %}

            {% block layout_breadcrumb_list_item %}
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"
                    {% if key is same as(categoryId) %}aria-current="page"{% endif %}
                    {% if breadcrumbCategory.type != 'folder' %}
                        itemprop="itemListElement"
                        itemscope
                        itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem"
                    {% endif %}>
                    {% if breadcrumbCategory.type == 'folder' %}
                        {{ name }}
                    {% else %}
                        <a href="{{ category_url(breadcrumbCategory) }}"
                           class="breadcrumb-link {% if key is same as(categoryId) %} is-active{% endif %}"
                           title="{{ name }}"
                           {% if category_linknewtab(breadcrumbCategory) %}target="_blank"{% endif %}
                           itemprop="item">
                            <link itemprop="url"
                                  href="{{ category_url(breadcrumbCategory) }}"/>
                            <span class="breadcrumb-title" itemprop="name">{{ name }}</span>
                        </a>
                        <meta itemprop="position" content="{{ position }}"/>

                        {% set position = position + 1 %}
                    {% endif %}
                </li>
            {% endblock %}

            {% block layout_breadcrumb_placeholder %}
                {{ parent() }}
            {% endblock %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% endblock %}
```